# Google chrome not launching

Tags: google-chrome

I am not able to launch chrome in Ubunut 18.04.3. When I tried to launch it from terminal I am getting the below error

```
$ google-chrome
[0830/111137.812090:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(207)] open /home/praveen/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/settings.dat: Permission denied (13)
```

Comment: FYI:  If you are actually using 18.04.3; you're ~18 months behind on upgrades & security fixes; as an updated 18.04 system will report itself as 18.04.5.  You can view https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ for the date of the ISO release, but installed systems upgrade to that version more than a week prior to the ISO release date.

Comment: Quite a few upgrades to chrome in that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix permission for `~/.config` folder with

```
sudo chown -R praveen:praveen /home/praveen/.config
```

and reboot.